# Is there a framework in Cocoa to create and manipulate ISO disk image?

Tags: cocoa, macos, iso

I want to ask whether there is a framework of Cocoa to create and manipulate ISO disk image. Actually, I want to find one Cocoa alternative for .NET DiscUtils(http://discutils.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create ISO images on the Mac, you can call `hdiutil`.  See `man hdiutil`.

Start by putting your files in a temporary directory, say, `/tmp/xyz/volume`.  (Use `mkdtemp`).  Then run:

```
$ hdiutil create -srcfolder /tmp/xyz/volume -format UDTO /tmp/xyz/image.cdr
```

This will create a "CDR Master" image.  You can then convert it to ISO:

```
$ hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o /path/to/image.iso /tmp/xyz/image.cdr
```

You can then delete the temporary directory.

Now, I know that this isn't a "framework" per se.  Instead you're calling external programs to do the work for you.  You'll need to learn how to use `fork`/`exec`, `popen`, `NSTask`, or one of the other variants.

As an alternative, you could build a copy of `mkisofs` and place that inside your application bundle.  The interface to `mkisofs` is somewhat nicer for creating ISO images, it's just not bundled with Mac OS X the way `hdiutil` is.

Comment: `hdiutil` seems to use the [DiskImages](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/tree/master/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework) private framework internally (mentioned in manual). So there is indeed a framework; it is just not public to users.